# core(M) SIMD instruction for multiplication equivalent to __QADD16 for addition

Tags: simd, cortex-m

For some reason, I could not find a SIMD instruction for multiplication of 16-bit without additional sum/substraction. The closest I could find is [__SMUAD](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Core/html/group__intrinsic__SIMD__gr.html#gae326e368a1624d2dfb4b97c626939257). Why it is missing?

Comment: Multiplication of what?  16-bit integer elements producing 16-bit elements with the low-half multiply results?  Which version of Cortex-M, like M7?

Comment: @PeterCordes, you are right. M4. But they should have the same SIMD instructions